# MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I currently have replication setup on MySQL 4.1 (master, named radius) to MySQL 5.0 (slave, named app1).

We got a new server and I installed MySQL 5.1 (named app2).

I setup app2 to replicate data from app1. If I manually run any queries on app1 they are replicated perfectly to app2, but any data being replicated on app1 coming from radius does not reflect on app2.

iow, i have master -> slave/master -> slave setup, but the last link in the chain isn't working.

any ideas?

Comment: Recommend question be moved to Server Fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the [-log-slave-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) option on B (app1 in your case) in a `A -> B -> C` configuration.

> Normally, a slave does not log to its own binary log any updates that are received from a master server. This option tells the slave to log the updates performed by its SQL thread to its own binary log.